# Placing Icon/Image upon a SVG shape properly?

Tags: javascript, css, html, svg, d3.js

Hope you guys can give me some pointers to how this can be accomplished.

I have these Regions which is svg path´s. Each region here is an individual svg path: [image]

I then need to place an image/icon/text, anything really, inside these. It doesnt matter where, but somewhere middle ish. And that seems pretty easy, just take place it in the middle of the path tag, But no. A region like Japan here, would make an icon centered to it, appear in the middle of the water: [image]

So how do i place my image/icon on these svg paths, so thats its somewhat centered, AND within the region?

PS. These regions can be zoomed in on, and i can pan around. Its also random which regions will have this image/icon on them, so i cannot hardcode positions into this. Hope you understand.

Here you can see how the regions are looped out: [image]

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Maybe you can modify the position of the image/icon/text with CSS and locate it in the right position for each SVG ... ? Show some parts of the code...

Comment: Just add the image into the SVG as an `<image>` element - http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/image-element.html

Comment: I should proberly have mentioned, that this is done dynamicly as its a browser game. I cannot "hardcode" its position. The regions are also zoomable and can pan on it. Ill update the question with this to

Comment: This issue may be interesting for the #D3js, #topojson community which work a lot with dynamic client side svg maps. The issue is at play with Japan, Indonesia, Philippines, France & its dependencies, and few others.

Comment: Yes both those, and my game supports custom made maps, so people could in theory make donut regions.. Im not really sure how to approach this issue. :(, I may have to create these points on map creation, and not handle it dynamic. :( I hope more can give an idea to this.

Comment: Further research shows that i may need to find the centroid of paths d attribute. Still trying to find out how thou

Answer (score 1):

Digging into [Snapsvg's](http://snapsvg.io/) `isPointInside` [method](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Snap.path.isPointInside) may yield some insight into checking whether your center coordinate is over water.

Comment: Ah interesting, thats very handy for future features. Thanks for showing that to me :)